# eclipse tomcat8 starts up very slow

Tags: eclipse, java-8, tomcat8

I'm developing web application using java8, tomcat8, jersey2.16, angularjs.

I'm having problem when starting up tomcat server.
It works well, don't have any errors,
but it just takes more then 10 minutes for starting up tomcat server.

I've tried TLD scanning optimize, jvm entropy option
but it didn't effect start up speed.

```
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.444 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:prg_web' did not find a matching property.
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.474 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Oct 7 2015 18:25:21 UTC
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.28.0
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_202-b08
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\prg\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\prg\apache-tomcat-8.0.28
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.476 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:59520
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.476 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -javaagent:C:\prg\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\411\0\.cp\lib\javaagent-shaded.jar
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.476 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\prg\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.476 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\prg\apache-tomcat-8.0.28
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.476 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\prg\workspace
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.476 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\prg\apache-tomcat-8.0.28\endorsed
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.476 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\prg\workspace\Servers\Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost-config\logging.properties
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.476 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.476 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.476 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.477 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot/bin/client;C:/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot/bin;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\j2kim\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\j2kim\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\bin;;;C:\prg\eclipse;;.
29-Jun-2021 16:54:02.746 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
29-Jun-2021 16:54:07.865 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
29-Jun-2021 16:54:07.870 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
29-Jun-2021 16:54:07.879 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
29-Jun-2021 16:54:07.879 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 6096 ms
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.172 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.172 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.182 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init ContextConfig: Initializing
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.183 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig Processing context [] configuration file [file:/C:/prg/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/conf/context.xml]
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.194 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig Successfully processed context [] configuration file [file:/C:/prg/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/conf/context.xml]
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.287 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart ContextConfig: Processing START
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.287 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart Context [] will parse web.xml and web-fragment.xml files with validation:false and namespaceAware:false
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.445 FINE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init ContextConfig: Initializing
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.445 FINE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig Processing context [/prg] configuration file [file:/C:/prg/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/conf/context.xml]
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.447 FINE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig Successfully processed context [/prg] configuration file [file:/C:/prg/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/conf/context.xml]
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.462 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.authenticatorConfig Configured an authenticator for method NONE
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.462 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart Pipeline Configuration:
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.462 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.462 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.462 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart ======================
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.498 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanResourcePaths No TLD files were found in resource path [/WEB-INF/].
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.693 FINE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart ContextConfig: Processing START
29-Jun-2021 16:54:09.694 FINE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart Context [/prg] will parse web.xml and web-fragment.xml files with validation:false and namespaceAware:false
29-Jun-2021 16:55:07.792 FINE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.authenticatorConfig Configured an authenticator for method NONE
29-Jun-2021 16:55:07.792 FINE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart Pipeline Configuration:
29-Jun-2021 16:55:07.792 FINE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator
29-Jun-2021 16:55:07.792 FINE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve
29-Jun-2021 16:55:07.792 FINE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart ======================
29-Jun-2021 16:55:07.846 FINE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanResourcePaths No TLD files were found in resource path [/WEB-INF/].
29-Jun-2021 17:05:16.958 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
29-Jun-2021 17:05:16.981 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
29-Jun-2021 17:05:16.983 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 669091 ms
```

This is the log when starting up tomcat server.
After scanning TLD files, it takes about 10 minutes to start.
I have no idea what is happening between there.

Is there any solution for this?
It's very inefficient specially when debugging...
It takes 10 minutes for just changing single line in Java...

Comment: Did you try disabling all breakpoints? Some breakpoints can really slow down the startup sequence.

Comment: Yes, I tried disabling all breakpoints, but it didn't work.